# Why am I getting a type error?

Tags: python, types

```
import time

def average(numbers):
    "Return the average (arithmetic mean) of a sequence of numbers."
    return sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers)) 

#example function

def domath(a,b,c):
    a+b+c
    a*b*c
    a/b/c
    a-b-c
    a^b
    b^c


def timedcalls(n, fn, *args):
    times=[]
    if type(n)==int:
        t0 = time.clock()
        for rep in range(n):
            t0 = time.clock()
            fn(*args)
            t1 = time.clock()
            times.append(t1-t0)
    else:
        start=time.clock()
        while time.clock-start<int(n):
            t0 = time.clock()
            fn(*args)
            t1 = time.clock()
            times.append(t1-t0)    
    return min(times), average(times), max(times)

print timedcalls(5.0, domath, 1,2,3)
```

This code works fine with int types, but for some reason if I use a float it gives me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 29, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 22, in timedcalls
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'
```

this line:

```
return min(times), average(times), max(times)
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while time.clock-start<int(n):
```

should be

```
while time.clock()-start<int(n):
```

You're not calling the `time.clock` function

Note in the traceback where it says it can't do subtraction between `'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'`